# Error in compilation with Geolocator pluggin

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm getting the current error when compiling a project with [Geolocator pluggin](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator):

```
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-2.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-2.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
      position.put("is_mocked", location.isMock());
                                        ^
  symbol:   method isMock()
  location: variable location of type Location
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I have already created another project to test if the error would occur, and when importing the package, the error occurs as well. I followed the gradle.properties configuration
and set the compileSdkVersion to 30 and checked the Flutter Doctor too, everything is ok, but the error still persists. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: I'm getting the same error too when add geolocator it worked 2 days ago!! and it works with old version of geolocator (6.2.1)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had the same trouble with geolocator 7.7.0. [Here](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)
To fix it, I changed in build.gradle compileSdkVersion from 29 to 31. That works for me.

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 29
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: After changing the compile version the error is gone, thanks!

Comment: This will also work with compileSdkVersion : 32, and targetSdkVersion 32.

Comment: i have same issue but my gradle latest version on 33 but still it gives me the error with geolocator_android-2.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/permission/PermissionUtils.java:27

Answer (score 8):

Try to change the **targetSdkVersion** and the **compileSdkVersion** to 31.

Don't forget to check this:

app/src/build.gradle:

- minSdkVersion 20

gradle.properties:

- android.useAndroidX=true
- android.enableJetifier=true

I hope to help you!

Answer (score 6):

In my case I changed the **compileSdkVersion to 30**.

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 30
   defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 21
     targetSdkVersion 29
   }
 }
```

> You should pin the geolocator to **version 7.6.2** (without using the caret ^ character) like so:

geolocator: 7.6.2
If you don't Flutter will still upgrade the geolocator plugin to version 7.7.0. More information can be found here: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax

Comment: Stuck for hours with the error. Finally came upon this answer. It really worked for me. 
android {
   compileSdkVersion 30
   defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 21
     targetSdkVersion 29
   }
 }

Comment: Perfect solution for me. Thanks man.

Comment: I was stuck on this for 3 hours. This finally solved it for me, thanks so much. For anyone else reading this, I also had to change compileSdkVersion to 31

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, i fix with download platform version `sdkmanager "platforms;android-31"`, and change compileVersion 31, minSdkVersion 21, and targetSdk 31.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrade flutter to 3.0.3.

I have updated the geolocator plugin to version 9.0.0 and the problem was solved.

Now everything is working fine.