# I have a problem in my flutter app. For some reason I can't run any of my flutter files. Every time I try to run it keeps giving me an error message

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

C:\Users\omar\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
^
symbol:   variable S
location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\Users\omar\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
position.put("is_mocked", location.isMock());
^
symbol:   method isMock()
location: variable location of type Location
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: have you tried flutter clean?

Comment: try to update the geolocator library

Answer (score 0):

#### First thought

You could indeed try to use the general `geolocator` package, but this uses `geolocator_android` so it'll likely not solve your issue. You are already using the latest version of `geolocator_android` it seems.

#### Already asked before

Looking online for the error, your problem has actually been answered on SA already:
[Error in compilation with Geolocator pluggin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487599/error-in-compilation-with-geolocator-pluggin)

### The Solution

The solution given is that you should update the `compileSDKVersion` in your `build.gradle` from 29 (or whatever it is now) to 31.

Alternatively you can probably also downgrade your version of the plugin.